# Map not showing up (using gmaps4rails gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, gmaps4rails

I'm using the gmaps4rails gem to generate a map containing several building locations on my University's campus.

However, I can't seem to get the map to show up.
There is a empty box that shows up, but that's about it.

Model: (Just included the lines related to gmaps4rails functionality purposes)

```
  acts_as_gmappable

  def gmaps4rails_address
    "#{self.name}, CA, Berkeley" 
  end
```

View:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>

<%= gmaps4rails(@json) %>
```

Controller:

```
  def map
     @json = Hall.all.to_gmaps4rails
  end
```

Application.js:

```
// This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into including all the files listed below.
// Add new JavaScript/Coffee code in separate files in this directory and they'll automatically
// be included in the compiled file accessible from http://example.com/assets/application.js
// It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom of the
// the compiled file.
//
//= require ./gmaps4rails/googlemaps.js
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
```

I also tried including `<%= stylesheet_link_tag 'gmaps4rails' %>` in the view. No luck.

My current screen looks like this: http://i50.tinypic.com/2q1z7dw.jpg

The contents in `@json` seem correct when I took a look at it. The map just doesn't show up for some reason.

Been at this for a couple of hours. I can't seem to figure out the problem. Looked through multiple past questions that seemed to be related to this issue.

Edit: Could it be the version of the gem? Mine is 1.5.6 
I noticed there is a 2.0.0.pre ... not sure what that is.

Edit2: Uhh ... not sure how to check that. Kind of a nub. I created a heroku application and tried to push my code onto there. I'm getting a `undefined local variable or method acts_as_gmappable for #<Class:0x00000002fd2c10>` now when I try to seed the database. Wondering if this has anything to do with my other problem.

Edit3: I believe so. I looked through quite a few posts as well and I seem to have everything correct. Then again, perhaps I am missing something ... still looking into it. Starting to drive me nuts.

(Oh, and im using JQuery Mobile as well. I found this past question [gmaps4rails on jQueryMobile don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735054/gmaps4rails-on-jquerymobile-dont-work?rq=1). Do I put the scripts in application.html.erb or mobile.html.erb? In addition, `<%= gmaps4rails(@json, false, false) %>` doesn't seem to work. Won't take 3 arguments.

As for part of `<div class="page" data-role="page" id="gmaps">`, am I supposed to incase `<%= gmaps4rails(@json, false, false) %>` in this div?

Comment: Are there any errors logged to the client console?

Comment: Have you restarted the application and also made sure you've got all the CSS and JS in place

Comment: all necessary js files aren't present, please read the doc

Comment: o, whoops. Yep, got the map working at this point. Gotta put up my answer to close this question.