# gmaps4rails + JQM with Ajax not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gmaps4rails, jquery-mobile

I am building a webapp with rails and JQM. The map shows up fine on my laptop and on my phone. The problem is when I am trying to launch it as a fullscreen app from a saved icon on my smartphone:

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

the map doesn't show up, just a white canvas.
It works when I disable ajax (data-ajax = false) but then the page is opened in my browser and leaves the webapp.

I followed the instructions in:
[gmaps4rails on jQueryMobile don't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7735054/gmaps4rails-on-jquerymobile-dont-work).
(I couldn't call gmaps4rails(@json, false, false) since gmaps4rails only accepts one parameter...)

Here is some of my code:

application.js:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.base
//= require gmaps4rails/gmaps4rails.googlemaps
//= require_tree .

$('#gmaps').live('pageshow',function(event){
    Gmaps.loadMaps();
});
```

layout:

```
  <%= javascript_include_tag "http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js" %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.5&sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/infobox/1.1.5/src/infobox.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.0.1/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/richmarker/src/richmarker-compiled.js"></script>

  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.mobile/1.3.0/jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.css", :media => "all" %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" user-scalable=no>
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
  <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
```

view:

```
<%= gmaps4rails(@markers_json) %>
<%= yield :scripts %>
```

Thanks for your help, this is driving me crazy!!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/apneadiving/1643990